# why all of values passed as 0 (not null) in ajax to controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I try to update some numeric values in a page, after fetching values to input and and put new values, by calling a function in ajax, all of the values passed as 0 to controller(.net core), i try many type of solutions but didn't solved.
this is part of page:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calculate_btn").click(function() {
    alert("hhhhhi");
    $.ajax({
      type: "Post",
      url: '@Url.Action("mylist","users")',
      data: JSON.stringify({
        product_no: $("#controller_pro_no").val(),
        insured_pro: $("#controller_ins").val(),
        pro_durate_m: $("#controller_pro_durate_m").val(),
      }),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      processData: false,
      success: function(mdata) {
        $("#fade1").hide();
        $("#modal").hide();
        $("#calculated_param").css('display', 'block');
        for (var n in mdata) {
          $("#product_index").text(JSON.stringify(n.product_index));
          $("#income_sell_pr_fertilizer").text(JSON.stringify(n.income_sell_pr_fertilizer));
          $("#net_profit_all").text(JSON.stringify(n.net_profit_all));
        }
      },
      success: function(mdata) {
        alert(mdata);
      },
      beforesend: function() {
        $("#fade1").show();
        $("#modal").show();
      },
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">product_no</label>
  <input id="controller_pro_no" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" value="@i.product_no" />
</div>
<button type="button" id="calculate_btn">calculate</button>
```

and controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult mylist(cost_info values, user u)
{
blmodel bluser = new blmodel();
u.username = Request.Cookies["username"];
var para = bluser.mylist(values, u);
return Json(para, JasonRequestBehavoir.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add the button and form HTML -  it may be relevant. For example you may need `$("#calculate_btn").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault()` - I would use a form submit event instead

Comment: Thanks for your reply and helping, but I've tried it by form and submit aaaand  unfortunately it didn't work!!

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify({
        product_no: $("#controller_pro_no").val(),
        insured_pro: $("#controller_ins").val(),
        pro_durate_m: $("#controller_pro_durate_m").val(),
      }))`

Comment: by removing content type and datatype it works, this is wired!! Thanks for helping

Comment: Feel free to delete the question

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` means the data passed from ajax is json type,if you don't want to remove it.you need to add `[FromBody]`.